# jQuery: Reseting form action after submit

Tags: jquery, forms, submit

I'd like to be able to submit a form to an alternative URL (which is not a problem) - and after submit set the form action to what it originally was.

```
$(".submitForExport").click(function() {

    // Saves current form action
    var originalAction = $(this).parents('form').attr('action');

    // Sets form action to export URL, submits and resets form action to previous action
    $(this).parents('form').attr('action', $('#alternativeUrl').val());
    $(this).parents('form').submit();
    $(this).parents('form').attr('action', originalAction);
});
```

However, the above code submits the form to the original action. It seems as if the submit action is triggered last?

If the last line is commented out, the form submits to the alternative URL as expected - but the form action is now off course set to the alternative URL.

Is there a way I post-submit can set the action to what is originally was? Or is there a better way to do this? Perhaps Ajax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to add a `return false;` at the end of your function. I guess your click event is catched on a submit button. So, your form is submitted twice: one with your manually triggered `.submit()` method, and another one at the end of the function, because of the `type="submit"` of the button.

Comment: Thanks! That did the trick! Should have tried that myself - but I thought it would suppress the form submit entirely.